# Why is the value of a React controlled input element not being updated properly from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, google-chrome-extension

When I run this code (which is part of a chrome extension) it should just fill out the information for the `#username` and `#password` inputs of a specific website, in this case https://wordplay.com/login.

However, the value of the input element does not really change. Visually, there is text in the input field, but when I inspect the element and look at the value attribute it remains blank. That is until I type something in the box manually. If I type something in the input then the value updates fine.

Also, when I try submitting the form they both change back to empty.

```
const username = document.getElementById('username');
username.value = request.username;

const password = document.getElementById('password');
password.value = request.password;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why Is This Happening?

That might have to do with whatever framework that site is using.

In this case, https://wordplay.com/login is using React and those fields are [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), so the logic on that form doesn't rely on the input's DOM value, but on the one in React's state. From the docs:

> [**Controlled Components**](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)
>
> In HTML, form elements such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with `setState()`.
>
> **We can combine the two by making the React state be the “single source of truth”**. Then the React component that renders a form also controls what happens in that form on subsequent user input. An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a “controlled component”.

#### ✨ Document.execCommand():

So, the easiest way to do that might be to focus the inputs and then use [`Document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand):

```js
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const password = document.getElementById('password');

username.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Alice');

password.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'password');
```

```html
<input id="username" />
<input id="password" />
```

#### ⚒️ Manually Dispatching Events:

Otherwise, you might try manually [dispatching a `change`, `input` and/or `blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) using the [Event() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) in those fields after you change their value. In this case, only `input` works.

Also, note `Event()`'s second optional argument contains a field, `bubbles`, that is `false` by default. **You need that one to be `true`**. Otherwise, this won't work, as React is listening for events on the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

Additionally, you might need to use [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) too, as that will update the `value` attribute on the DOM (the initial value on the field), while `element.value` will update the current value (and so the display value). In this case, though, it's not needed. For more on this see [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html).

This approach might have some timing issues you might need to handle using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) when updating multiple inputs, so if the first one works, I'd go for that one instead.

```js
const username = document.getElementById('username');

// This updates the value displayed on the input, but not the DOM (you can do that with setAttribute,
// but it's not needed here):
username.value = 'Bob';

// Dispatch an "input" event. In some cases, "change" would also work:
username.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));

// It looks like only one field will be updated if both events are dispatched
// straight away, so you could use a setTimeout here:

setTimeout(() => {
  const password = document.getElementById('password');
  password.value = 'password';
  password.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));    
});
```

```html
<input id="username" />
<input id="password" />
```

Comment: I tried this and the same thing happened. I have to manually update the field before the value changes.

Comment: @BrandonKirincich Can you share the site where you are testing the extension?

Comment: @BrandonKirincich Sorry, forgot to mention the `bubbles` option. That's `false` by default, so you need to set it to `true` for React to receive those events.

Comment: This worked perfectly for the username input but not for the password. When I check the value of the password field it is correct however it doesn't show visually and when I press the login button manually or via the extension then it says it is invalid. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @BrandonKirincich I think it's just a timing issue, try with the updated code, just wrapping the password field in a `setTimeout`.

Comment: @BrandonKirincich I think I've found a better solution with `execCommand()`.  ☝️